# Firebase Database URL cannot be determined - React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

I am using Firebase in my React Native app but getting the Error

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR:  can't determine firebase database URL. Be sure to include database URL option when calling firebase.initializeAPP()

This is my config.js file

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyA08uehn60xmtsw98BBlZnH0b8V6O-VuT8",
    authDomain: "rnfirebase-96621.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://rnfirebase-96621.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "rnfirebase-96621",
    storageBucket: "rnfirebase-96621.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "492662092859",
    appId: "1:492662092859:web:41ade14689b24eff49981e",
    measurementId: "G-6M8445HDXE"
  };
firebase.initializeApp({firebaseConfig});
```

And my App.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {firebaseConfig} from './config';
componentDidMount() {
    const myname = firebase.database().ref("users/name");
    myname.on("value",datasnap=>{
      alert(datasnap.val())
    })
 }
```

I have searched a lot but got no solution.
Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your call to `initializeApp`. Remove the `{}` from that call:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```